# How to retrieve my friends checkins details using facebook-java-api/facebook graph api

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am building a java app which integrates with my facebook account and fetches checkings details of my friends.

Steps that I followed:

1)  Download facebook-java-api and created a dynamic web project in eclipse.

2)  Refer the article to authenticate a user_https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/

3)  Refer the following URL to see checkin API refrences
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

On this page, under the “Searching” section I came across the https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin  link, when we click this URL it navigates to a page_https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=<.........>  (it automically creates a access token for you, provided that you are logged in your facebook account) and there I can seee my friends checkins details.

Now how can I integrate the same feature with my Java app?

Any other suggestion to retrieve friend’s checkins details and to show them on a jsp page.

Regards.

Comment: facebook-java-api is old, is there a specific version of the library you are using?

Comment: As such I am not using any specific library. I just downloaded “facebook-java-api-3.0.2-bin.zip" and integrated respective jars in my project But I didn’t use any of its library. For the authentication I referred https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ and which is authenticating a user via JavaScript.